# Hibernate query already fetched entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Is there a way in `hibernate`(or ORM in general) to query session managed collections, i.e get entity with max id, without hitting the database.

Right now I do this with `Java` stream API. It works and it is much faster than a database query. But I find myself doing this a lot in my current project. So I thought hibernate might already have an option to run queries "locally".

It is an desktop application so i am sure the DB won't change outside of this application.

Answer (score 0):

No @lazyCoding, HIBERNATE can't do it. Maybe http://josql.sourceforge.net/manual/introduction.html will help you.